# "Write an equation of line J, that passes through P, and is parallel to given line L"

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I apologise if this is too simple a level for this board.

The question is:

"Given the point $P(x_1,y_1)$ and the line $l$ with the equation $ax + by = c$:

Write an equation of the line $j$ that passes through $P$ and is perpendicular to $l$"

I am struggling to figure out this answer. I start with the given equation $l$ and reorient it into the form $y=ax+c$, essentially because I find that form easier to read for meaning. This, after canceling for $b$ in the given equation $l$ leaves me with:
$$y=\frac abx +\frac cb$$
Then, going by perpendicularity, I take the opposite reciprocal of the slope and end up with:
$$y_1=\frac bax_1 + ...$$

And, like that, I suddenly realise that I have no idea what to input for $c$ here. Thinking it through, the $c$ is the y-intercept. Sketching out two lines on a grid, it seems like c should be equal to the initial y-intercept added to the new y-intercept but I don't figure how to figure this. Initially, I just reversed the slope for $-a$ and swapped that in but I feel that the $b$ needs to be accounted for as that would influence the slope. Really, this question has made me realise I don't understand the meaning of the various equations of the line fully, which is really positive, if currently frustrating.

In addition, the book yields the answer $bx-ay=bx_1-ay_1$

This answer seems to confirm I'm reasonably lost. I don't see, from here, why the $a$ and $b$ have switched on both sides between $x$ and $y$. Or why the general $x$ and $y$ of the original equation are set equal to the new line's points. I feel like I may be approaching this entirely wrong, and will continue trying. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Also, again, I apologise if this is too low a level for this stackexchange. I am working on improving my math skills as an adult and live in an area where I have been unable to get math tutoring in English so I am working as I can by myself. Your help would be very kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't lost, you just quit too early.

$y_1=\frac bax_1+...$ gives you the value of the unknown intercept, $...=y_1-\frac bax_1$.

Hence,$$y=\frac bax+y_1-\frac bax_1.$$

Comment: I think I'm still a little lost.

If I'm correct in understanding you, we have: $y_1=\frac bax_1 + k$

We rewrite this to be: $k=y_1-\frac bax_1$

And substitute it back in, resulting in:
$$y=\frac bax + y_1-\frac bax_1$$

What confuses me here is the change in subscript. We have a given x and y. Are we subbing it all into the second equation j? If so, don't we have:
$$y_1 =\frac bax_1 +y_1 -\frac bax_1$$

Which would cancel down to $0$?

Or, are we setting it back into the original equation? Or just setting an arbitrary x and y which includes the point $P(x_1,y_1)$? Thank you for your help!

Comment: The line is defined by two unknown parameters. $y=mx+p$. The slope $m$ is determined from the orthogonality condition; the intercept $p$ is determined from the point inclusion constraint. $x$ is an independent variable and $y$ a dependent variable; all other parameters are constants.

Answer (score 0):

The lines that are perpendicular to the line with equation $ax+by=c$ are those with equation
$$
bx-ay=k
$$
Indeed, if $px+qy=r$ is perpendicular to $ax+by=c$, we have that
$$
ap+bq=0
$$
(the well known orthogonality relation), so we can choose $q=-a$ and $p=b$, as the coefficients of the equation of a line are determined up to a multiplicative non zero factor.

Now just impose that $bx-ay=k$ passes through the point $P(x_1,y_1)$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you made a mistake writting the equation of $l$: it's $$y=-\frac ab x +\frac cb.$$

You did good staff finding the begininf of the equation of $j$: $$y=\frac ba x+ k.$$

Now, you only have to find $k$. And this is esay since you now that $P$ is on $j$. Say that $P(3,2)$, we have:
$$2=\frac ba 3 +k$$
and the unknown is $k$.

About the equations of the form $ax+by+c=0$: those equations are more general than yours. Indeed, whith $y=mx+p$, we can not handle the "vertical" lines (cases where $a=0$ and so you can not divide by $a$).

You have to know that if $ax+by+c=0$ is an equation of $l$, so the vector $(a,b)$ is normal to $l$, and $(-b,a)$ is a director vector of $l$.

Comment: Thank you, I absolutely made that error with the negative sign in the post. Also, your advice on how $y=mx+p$ does not handle vertical lines is very helpful; thank you for explaining it!


With your solution, it is clear but I am being asked to find a general solution using $P(x_1,y_1)$. Subsituting these values I find:
$$y_1=\frac bax_1 + k$$

It is from here that I find difficulty. It seems, from Yves' answer below, that I must substitute k for the set value, but with: 
$$y = -\frac ab + \frac cb$$

I don't see where a substitution achieving this is allowed. I think this is my main problem.

Comment: I don't where you pick your $y=-\frac ab + \frac cb$.

From $y_1=\frac bax_1+k$, you can write $y_1 - \frac ba x_1 =k$: it exactly is what Yves has written.